# Should I hard code IAM credentials for CloudWatch logging within client apps?

Tags: .net, xamarin, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an IAM User that has programmatic access to the CloudWatch Log APIs via access / secret keys. I'm using the following policy to restrict it's access to just a specific `LogGroup`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:223237870883:log-group:/myappname/dev/client/uwp"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:223237870883:log-group:/myappname/dev/client/uwp:log-stream:*",
                "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:223237870883:log-group:/myappname/dev/client/uwp"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The keys will be shipped with a mobile app into the Android/iOS/Windows/macOS app stores. Each app has it's own key/Policy (the above is for the UWP app) that constrains it to its own CloudWatch `LogGroup` I create via CloudFormation.

My question is on the keys themselves. I can either put them in a configuration file or I can hard-code them into the binaries. I was going to hard-code them since I can't change the config files after the fact anyway - if I wanted to change them I'd need to ship a new version of the app regardless. It seemed like hard-coding them in the app make it a bit more difficult for someone to try and steal.

Worse case if they are stolen is that they flood me with CloudWatch logs. Is there anything I can do to try and prevent that? I tried to looking at Amplify and how it handles this but didn't see anything that stood out there.

Are there any problems with the approach that I've taken from a security perspective or is this pretty much par for the course?

As a side-note, I had integrated Visual Studio App Center logging originally but didn't want to deal with building a process to aggregate logs from App Center for clients and CloudWatch for my back-end. App Center seemed to work the same way - access key/client key with nothing that really stopped someone from stealing and logging outside of the app.

Appreciate any guidance anyone can offer on your experiences with this kind of thing. Not looking for *the right answer*. Wanting to see what other approaches folks have taken to see if I'm completely off the beaten path or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can prevent shipping credentials by hiding the credentials behind an API endpoint, which you can then rate-limit, secure, rotate access to with each app deployment etc.

While the worst case is that they can flood you with logs, if you already have a backend API, it is better to have a dedicated logging endpoint between you and Cloudwatch.

I wouldn't worry too much however, you're [granting the least privilege](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege) which is the most important factor.

Comment: I thought about that - I was trying to avoid having to pay for the API calls (even though they're not super expensive). CloudWatch logging using the SDK let me ingress at no cost whereas an API would require me to pay for the compute, API Gateway and Cloudfront bits. If that ends up being the only route then I'll look at it. It's a project I'm working on by myself without any funding so trying to keep my initial launch costs down as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - that was one of the biggest things I focused on for it. If I could get least privilege then the risk was small - other than potentially being spammed. At which point I could disable the access key for that 1 client app (albeit all users with that client) while the remaining clients continue to log.

Comment: Re-reading your post, I like the idea of an API that ships the credentials themselves. Then letting the app setup the logging and use CloudWatch locally. I'll take a look at that - I already have an app configuration API endpoint for app config. I can easily stick the credentials in that response. Only downside is the users would have to be authenticated first so I can't do any logging until auth is done. I'll think about it, thanks

Comment: No worries man, I understand - security always comes at a cost but in this case, it's not the biggest worst "denial of wallet" attack one could do. They could hammer other longer running endpoints to cost you money if they wanted to.

As of now, it's around a $1 for a million calls but if you're in your 1st 12 months with AWS, you get 1 mil free every month which should be plenty - see https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/

If on a small project, your policy is perfect - I wouldn't worry about an API.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Or that's an idea too - you could have a key that is rotated weekly which the client can call for.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger The beauty of the cloud is that any and everything is possible - go ahead with what works best for you right now.

I know enterprise projects used by millions of customers daily who have open logging endpoints - just ensure the IAM policy is guarded well :)

No worries!

Comment: Sounds good - thanks for the input!